# Why my website looks different on computer?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Why my website looks different on computer? on my localhost it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxhp3.jpg
and when i upload my files on host website and check my website it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOnmu.jpg
I’m using HTML5,CSS3 and Bootstrap 4, anyone know how to solve it?, i used css3 only for the size of carousel thing, padding at navbar and at the HR tag, first i thought the host don’t recognize the css file but why my ABOUT ME button is not on the right position i used only bootstrap classes for button,
Sorry for my bad english, hope you answer to my question.
P.S: On mobile or tablet looks very good, but on pc it looks like in the image.

Comment: Please provide some code or create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) example to show us your code to be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing actual code, but you should check your folder/directory structure and make sure that they match. Sometimes if you upload the files, the paths may not match and cause distortion.

A recommendation would be to reopen your website back in Chrome and open up Chrome Developer. Then down in the console, see if you are getting any errors in terms of Chrome not being able to find certain files.

**EDIT**

Inside your HTML, in your head section, try adding this line:

```
<base href="/">
```

Before you link your CSS files. So your index.html head section would like as follows:

```
<head>
    <title>Tudor Alexandru</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="./favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Comment: I'm getting this error "2(index):1 Refused to apply style from 'http://tudor-alexandru.000webhostapp.com/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled." idk what it is.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a code snippet. This may help counteract the MIME error you are receiving.

Comment: yea man, thanks, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any code snippet, so the only hint we can get is the `Beginner Web Developer` in the screenshot.

My guess is your CSS contains positioning based on `%`. If you have two screens with different sizes, the `%` won't resolve the same way.

Comment: This is my code and the folder: https://imgur.com/a/r3InTYR, now padding on navbar is ok but the size of carousel dosen't work, https://imgur.com/a/4PDXH1T, i used px for the size.

Comment: @TudorAlexandru DON'T  paste code as images! Add your code on your answer or recreate an example on fiddle